# Fb.Login() doesn't get extended permissions

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I want to post on users facebook timeline from my application. I added js sdk as in facebook tutorial and tried a simple example.

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'xxx',
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.3'
    });
};

    (function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

This is how I want to get the accessToken:

```
$(document).on('click', '#temporary-id', function () {
FB.login(function (response) {
    var perms = response.authResponse.grantedScopes;
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    console.log(uid);
    console.log(perms);
    console.log(accessToken);
}, {
    scope: "publish_actions,publish_stream",
    return_scopes: true
});
```

But doesn't return me permission to publish, only this three: **email,contact_email,public_profile**. What is wrong? How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`publish_stream` is deprecated since many years. Why would you ask for a permission that does not exist anymore?

Anyway, I assume you are trying as a user without a role in the App. Please read the docs about Login Review: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review

Without review, most permissions only work as App Admin/Developer/Tester.

Comment: how can I test my application as developer without rewiev?

Comment: you just do ;) - use the app with a user account that is admin, developer or tester.